# PySide, QtWebKit - loadFinished signal is never emitted

Tags: pyside, qtwebkit, qwebview

```
import sys
from PySide import QtGui, QtWebKit, QtCore

class WebPageProcessor(object):

    def __init__(self, browser):
        self.browser = browser
        self.browser.loadFinished.connect(self.test)
        self.browser.load('http://google.com')

    def test(self, ok):
        print(ok)


class Browser(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.init_ui()
        bot = WebPageProcessor(self.browser)

    def init_ui(self):
        self.browser = QtWebKit.QWebView()

        grid = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        grid.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        grid.addWidget(self.browser, 0, 0)
        self.setLayout(grid)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    browser = Browser()
    browser.show()
    app.exec_()
```

'Browser' class is the UI browser and 'WebPageProcessor' is the class which controls it.

I have binded 'loadFinished' signal to the browser but **it's never called**.

If I resign from 'WebPageProcessor' class and put all it's code into 'init_ui' method, then the signal is emitted correctly.

What's the reason and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `loadFinished` certainly is emitted. But the `test` slot will never be called, because it gets deleted immediately after it is connected. This is because you're allowing the instance of `WebPageProcessor` to be garbage-collected once `__init__` has returned.

Try this instead:

```
    self.bot = WebPageProcessor(self.browser)
```